# Media images not showing in custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-1, custom, custom-attributes, media-images

I have a problem, I have created a custom module in my Magento site, so in that module I'm calling custom attributes to display some content and images, but when I'm adding media image in this attribute image never shows on the frontend. In inspect element I can saw image in this format. Any suggestion?

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-amsrc="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" img-pages="" 2017device-benefits2.jpg"}}"="" style="margin-bottom:10px;" width="80" height="45" alt="Benefits">
```

Thank You

Comment: what you are trying to archive?

Comment: I have a custom product attribute as content and I am inserting media image here. Than I am using that attribute in my custom module to display on frontend.

Comment: Have you created image attribute for this one?

Comment: because you image data is wrong. you can revert base64 to png will see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and it is fixed. I saw the image has `data-amsrc` attribute. it is added by amasty "Google Page Speed Optimizer" module. There is config in admin to ignore images contain certain classes.

in my case, this module also added style `display:block` to all images in my site. I change config `Lazy Load Script => Native JavaScript Lazy Script` fixed both issues

hope this helps you

thanks

Comment: That was a problem in my case also, I disable Amasty Lazy Loading and everything works well. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. It saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Wenping Guo resolution.  We solved the same issue by changing Amasty's Google PageSpeed Optimizer's Image Optimization > Lazy Load > Lazy Load Script from JQuery Lazy Script to Native Javascript Lazy Script resolved the issue for us.

The strange thing for us though was that the issue only affected some of the product images, not all.